# Syntax Question: Looping files in sequence

Tags: python, loops, file, syntax

How do I create the loop to perform edits on my files?

I have 1201 files to edit.

I would want to repeat this three lines of code for all my 1201 files.
I can't seems to get the syntax right.

My idea is as such:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io
from scipy.io import savemat

for (i) in range(1200):  #start of loop
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat('GT_IMG_[i].mat')
    mat1=np.asarray(mat)
    savemat("GT_IMG_[i].mat"), {"image_info":mat1})
                         #End of loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the variable `i` as part of the filename strings, use a formatted string, e.g.:

```
for i in range(1200):
    mat = scipy.io.loadmat(f'GT_IMG_{str(i)}.mat')
```

Also you've got an extra parentheses or something going on in your last line.

Comment: You don't need to cast to string.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how scipy is working but I see at your code that you need to put the `'GT_IMG_[i].mat'` in a f-string like that: `f'GT_IMG_{i}.mat'`